# XML Cross Apply Multiple Rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

Trying to get the following information using XML but struggling - could anyone assist? I need to get the repeating workparty info

i.e.

```xml
<pyWorkParty REPEATINGTYPE="PageGroup">
<rowdata REPEATINGINDEX="Underwriter">
```

I need this as one row with the next column being the name:

```
<pyFirstName>RANDOM</pyFirstName>
```

followed by the second repeating type being OrigUW and then third which is DATHandler

could anyone assist. ive had a go see below but wont work (i'm not really sure what Im doing as dont work with XMl data often)

```sql
SELECT
 t.TransID,
 --pyFullName.value('.','varchar(MAX)') as [Value],
 --pxPartyRole.value('.','varchar(MAX)') as [Value],
 --pyFullName.value('.','varchar(MAX)') as [Value],
 --t.TransXml,
 w.x.value('(pyWorkParty/RowData[@REPEATINGINDEX = "Underwriter"]/pyFullName/text())[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') as UndewrwriterName

FROM  #T t
CROSS APPLY TransXML.nodes('pagedata') as w(x)
```

```xml
<pagedata>
  <pyOrigUserWorkgroup>InternationalCasualty</pyOrigUserWorkgroup>
  <pxUpdateSystemID>pega</pxUpdateSystemID>
  <pzIndexCount>20</pzIndexCount>
  <pyResolvedOrgUnit>DelegatedAuthorities</pyResolvedOrgUnit>
  <pxUpdateDateTime>20220224T131425.174 GMT</pxUpdateDateTime>
  <pyResolvedTimestamp>20220224T131424.953 GMT</pyResolvedTimestamp>
  <pxApplication>DA</pxApplication>
  <pxCreateDateTime>20220208T160522.710 GMT</pxCreateDateTime>
  <pxUrgencyWork>0</pxUrgencyWork>
  <pyOrigOrgUnit>Casualty</pyOrigOrgUnit>
  <pxInsName>B-2511</pxInsName>
  <pyResolvedOrg>RANDONLondon</pyResolvedOrg>
  <pxSaveDateTime>20220224T131425.175 GMT</pxSaveDateTime>
  <pyResolvedUserWorkgroup>DelegatedAuthorities_DA</pyResolvedUserWorkgroup>
  <pxApplicationVersion>01.01.01</pxApplicationVersion>
  <pyHasAttachments>true</pyHasAttachments>
  <pzInsKey>RANDON-DA-WORK B-2511</pzInsKey>
  <pyOwnerOrgUnit>Casualty</pyOwnerOrgUnit>
  <pyOwnerOrg>RANDONLondon</pyOwnerOrg>
  <pyOrigUserID>OJakob</pyOrigUserID>
  <pyResolvedUserID>thill</pyResolvedUserID>
  <pxUpdateOpName>RANDOM(2) Hill</pxUpdateOpName>
  <pxUpdateCounter>38</pxUpdateCounter>
  <pxUpdateOperator>thill</pxUpdateOperator>
  <pxUpdateOrgUnit>DelegatedAuthorities</pxUpdateOrgUnit>
  <pyID>B-2511</pyID>
  <pyOwnerDivision>Underwriting</pyOwnerDivision>
  <pyStyle>pdf</pyStyle>
  <pyIsDataPageRefreshed>true</pyIsDataPageRefreshed>
  <pyWorkIDPrefix>B-</pyWorkIDPrefix>
  <pyOrigUserDivision>Underwriting</pyOrigUserDivision>
  <pyOrigDivision>Underwriting</pyOrigDivision>
  <pyResolvedTime>1372141.0</pyResolvedTime>
  <pyResolvedDivision>RiskAndCompliance</pyResolvedDivision>
  <pxObjClass>RANDON-DA-Work-Binder</pxObjClass>
  <pxCreateOperator>OJakob</pxCreateOperator>
  <pyOrigOrg>RANDONLondon</pyOrigOrg>
  <pyResolvedUserDivision>RiskAndCompliance</pyResolvedUserDivision>
  <pzIndexOwnerKey>RANDON-DA-WORK B-2511</pzIndexOwnerKey>
  <BinderSectionOBRef>22N44389AANR</BinderSectionOBRef>
  <pxCreateSystemID>pega</pxCreateSystemID>
  <pyLabel>INSURANCE COBROKERS INC</pyLabel>
  <pxCreateOpName>RANDOM Jakob</pxCreateOpName>
  <pzStatus>valid</pzStatus>
  <Queries REPEATINGTYPE="PageList" />
  <Compliance>
    <pxObjClass>RANDON-DA-Data-Compliance</pxObjClass>
  </Compliance>
  <CaseDetails>
    <ExpiryDate>20230228T000000.000 GMT</ExpiryDate>
    <BusinessType>New</BusinessType>
    <CreateDate>20220208</CreateDate>
    <Name>INSURANCE BROKERSBROKERS INC</Name>
    <pxObjClass>RANDON-DA-Data-CaseDetails</pxObjClass>
    <UniqRef>11511</UniqRef>
    <InceptionDate>20220301T000000.000 GMT</InceptionDate>
    <CaseStatus>Approved</CaseStatus>
    <TaskType>NB</TaskType>
    <TaskTypeLabel>New Binder</TaskTypeLabel>
    <AGReferenceID>2202AG11511BI</AGReferenceID>
    <AssignDate REPEATINGTYPE="PropertyGroup">
      <rowdata REPEATINGINDEX="UW">20220217</rowdata>
      <rowdata REPEATINGINDEX="DA">20220224</rowdata>
    </AssignDate>
    <AssignmentStatus REPEATINGTYPE="PropertyGroup">
      <rowdata REPEATINGINDEX="UW">New</rowdata>
      <rowdata REPEATINGINDEX="DA">Resolved</rowdata>
    </AssignmentStatus>
  </CaseDetails>
  <pyWorkParty REPEATINGTYPE="PageGroup">
    <rowdata REPEATINGINDEX="Underwriter">
      <pyFullName>RANDOM Jakob</pyFullName>
      <pyWorkPartyUri>OJakob</pyWorkPartyUri>
      <pxPartyRole>Underwriter</pxPartyRole>
      <pyUserName>RANDOM Jakob</pyUserName>
      <pxObjClass>Data-Party-Operator</pxObjClass>
      <pyFirstName>RANDOM</pyFirstName>
      <pyUserIdentifier>OJakob</pyUserIdentifier>
      <pyPartyLabel>Underwriter Handler</pyPartyLabel>
      <pzIndexOwnerKey>RANDON-DA-WORK B-2511</pzIndexOwnerKey>
      <pyLabel>RANDOM Jakob</pyLabel>
      <pxSubscript>Underwriter</pxSubscript>
      <pyLastName>Jakob</pyLastName>
      <pyWorkBasket>UWCasualty</pyWorkBasket>
      <pyEmail1>OJakob@RANDONlondon.co.uk</pyEmail1>
      <pzIndexes REPEATINGTYPE="PropertyGroup">
        <rowdata REPEATINGINDEX="PartyURI">1</rowdata>
      </pzIndexes>
    </rowdata>
    <rowdata REPEATINGINDEX="OrigUW">
      <pyFullName>RANDOM Jakob</pyFullName>
      <pyWorkPartyUri>OJakob</pyWorkPartyUri>
      <pxPartyRole>OrigUW</pxPartyRole>
      <pyUserName>RANDOM Jakob</pyUserName>
      <pxObjClass>Data-Party-Operator</pxObjClass>
      <pyFirstName>RANDOM</pyFirstName>
      <pyUserIdentifier>OJakob</pyUserIdentifier>
      <pyPartyLabel>Underwriter</pyPartyLabel>
      <pzIndexOwnerKey>RANDON-DA-WORK B-2511</pzIndexOwnerKey>
      <pyLabel>RANDOM Jakob</pyLabel>
      <pxSubscript>OrigUW</pxSubscript>
      <pyLastName>Jakob</pyLastName>
      <pyWorkBasket>UWCasualty</pyWorkBasket>
      <pyEmail1>OJakob@RANDONlondon.co.uk</pyEmail1>
      <pzIndexes REPEATINGTYPE="PropertyGroup">
        <rowdata REPEATINGINDEX="PartyURI">2</rowdata>
      </pzIndexes>
    </rowdata>
    <rowdata REPEATINGINDEX="DATHandler">
      <pyFullName>RANDOM(2) Hill</pyFullName>
      <pyWorkPartyUri>thill</pyWorkPartyUri>
      <pxPartyRole>DATHandler</pxPartyRole>
      <pyUserName>RANDOM(2) Hill</pyUserName>
      <pxObjClass>Data-Party-Operator</pxObjClass>
      <pyFirstName>RANDOM(2)</pyFirstName>
      <pyUserIdentifier>thill</pyUserIdentifier>
      <pyPartyLabel>DAT Handler</pyPartyLabel>
      <pzIndexOwnerKey>RANDON-DA-WORK B-2511</pzIndexOwnerKey>
      <pyLabel>RANDOM(2) Hill</pyLabel>
      <pxSubscript>DATHandler</pxSubscript>
      <pyLastName>Hill</pyLastName>
      <pyWorkBasket>DelegatedAuthorities_DA</pyWorkBasket>
      <pyEmail1>thill@RANDONlondon.co.uk</pyEmail1>
      <pzIndexes REPEATINGTYPE="PropertyGroup">
        <rowdata REPEATINGINDEX="PartyURI">19</rowdata>
      </pzIndexes>
    </rowdata>
  </pyWorkParty>
</pagedata>
```

Comment: What database system are you using?

Comment: wow thats a quick reply, sorry its SQL Server, 2016 i think?

Comment: XML element and attribute names are generally case-sensitive.

Answer (score 2):

It's not altogether clear from your question what your expected results are.

From the example result it seems that you're wanting the XML of the required elements, such as via:

```sql
SELECT
  t.TransID,
  pyWorkParty.query(N'(rowdata[@REPEATINGINDEX="Underwriter"]/pyFullName)[1]') as UndewrwriterName,
  pyWorkParty.query(N'(rowdata[@REPEATINGINDEX="OrigUW"]/pyFullName)[1]') as OriginalUnderwriter,
  pyWorkParty.query(N'(rowdata[@REPEATINGINDEX="DATHandler"]/pyFullName)[1]') as DelegatedAuthorityTeam
FROM  #T t
CROSS APPLY TransXML.nodes('pagedata/pyWorkParty[@REPEATINGTYPE="PageGroup"]') as pagedata(pyWorkParty);
```

But from the attempted SQL query it seems like you're wanting the text contents of those elements, such as via:

```sql
SELECT
  t.TransID,
  pyWorkParty.value(N'(rowdata[@REPEATINGINDEX="Underwriter"]/pyFullName/text())[1]', N'nvarchar(max)') as UndewrwriterName,
  pyWorkParty.value(N'(rowdata[@REPEATINGINDEX="OrigUW"]/pyFullName/text())[1]', N'nvarchar(max)') as OriginalUnderwriter,
  pyWorkParty.value(N'(rowdata[@REPEATINGINDEX="DATHandler"]/pyFullName/text())[1]', N'nvarchar(max)') as DelegatedAuthorityTeam
FROM  #T t
CROSS APPLY TransXML.nodes('pagedata/pyWorkParty[@REPEATINGTYPE="PageGroup"]') as pagedata(pyWorkParty);
```

Comment: This works exactly how i want, I always read stuff on here but never posted, I dont think I've appreciated how helpful this community is! Thanks so much

Comment: Hi bit of a long shot but this really helped but I'm struggling to go down a level now, within the repeatingindex of underwriter, if there was another repeating type called propertygroup, i need to take the row data from estpolicycount where the repeatingindex is total12..

Comment: example:      <EstPolicyCount REPEATINGTYPE="PropertyGroup">
          <rowdata REPEATINGINDEX="Total12">30</rowdata>
          <rowdata REPEATINGINDEX="NonSME">30</rowdata>
        </EstPolicyCount>

Comment: @NicholasCampbell comments aren't really the place for big chunks of code or data. If you ask a new question against the `sql-server` tag I'll keep an eye out for it. Don't forget to include the example XML as well as the SQL query/ies you've attempted so far.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
select  G.n.value('./@REPEATINGTYPE', 'nvarchar(50)') as RType
,       A.n.value('./@REPEATINGINDEX', 'nvarchar(50)') as RIndex
,       A.n.value('pyUserName[1]', 'nvarchar(50)') as UserName
from @xmltbl t
cross apply [data].nodes('pagedata/pyWorkParty') G(n)
cross apply g.n.nodes('rowdata') A(n)
```

If it doesn't bring you what you want, please, provide some sample table with desired result, because from your question it isn't very clear.